# Outlook VBA Macro to move mail from subfolder to subfolder

Tags: vba, outlook

I am currently encountering a slight issue with running a VBA script.

```
Sub MovePathErrors(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

If Item.Attachments.Count > 0 Then

Dim attCount As Long
Dim strFile As String
Dim sFileType As String

attCount = Item.Attachments.Count

For i = attCount To 1 Step -1
      strFile = Item.Attachments.Item(i).FileName

      sFileType = LCase$(Right$(strFile, 4))

    Select Case sFileType
        Case ".ber"
    ' do something if the file types are found
    ' this code moves the message
      Item.Move (Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders(".PathErrors"))

   ' stop checking if a match is found and exit sub
       GoTo endsub
      End Select
  Next i

End If
```

Basically the above code moves all the mail items with attachments that contain a .ber file type from my inbox folder to the '.PathErrors' subfolder - this works perfectly.

However what I want to do is move mails from a different sub folder '.AllPathMails' to '.PathErrors' if they contain an attachment with a .ber file type.

I tried the following code but it doesn't work:

```
Sub MovePathErrors(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

If Item.Attachments.Count > 0 Then

Dim attCount As Long
Dim strFile As String
Dim sFileType As String

attCount = Item.Attachments.Count

For i = attCount To 1 Step -1
      strFile = Item.Attachments.Item(i).FileName

      sFileType = LCase$(Right$(strFile, 4))

    Select Case sFileType
        Case ".ber"
    ' do something if the file types are found
    ' this code moves the message
      Item.Move (Session.GetDefaultFolder(".AllPathMails").Folders(".PathErrors"))

   ' stop checking if a match is found and exit sub
       GoTo endsub
      End Select
  Next i

End If
```

Am I doing something wrong here?
I believe it could be the 'Session.GetDefaultFolder' part that's faulty?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I'm struggling to execute the first piece of code to move the emails with the ".ber" attachment. Please could you indicate how to execute the code and where to place it.

Comment: Hi @Jean-PierreOosthuizen and thanks. Please see Diane Poremsky's implementation: [link] (http://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/use-vba-move-messages-based-values-fields)

Comment: Where is the ".AllPathMails" folder and ".PathErrors" folder exactly? Are they a sub folder of your inbox or part of your cabinet?

Comment: @Jean-PierreOosthuizen Yes, these are just sub folders of my outlook's inbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work if

the two folders are named **.AllPathMails** and **.PathErrors**

AND

They are SubFolders of your Inbox and depicted below:

[image]

```
 Option Explicit
 Sub MoveEmailsBetweenFoldersDependingOnAttachmentType()

      Dim AllPathMailsFolderList As Outlook.MAPIFolder
      Set AllPathMailsFolderList = GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders(".AllPathMails")

      Dim CurrentItem As Object
      Dim CurrentAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
      Dim AttachmentName As String
      Dim AttachmentFileType As String

      For Each CurrentItem In AllPathMailsFolderList.Items

           If CurrentItem.Attachments.Count > 0 Then

                For Each CurrentAttachment In CurrentItem.Attachments

                     AttachmentName = CurrentAttachment.FileName
                     AttachmentFileType = LCase$(Right$(AttachmentName, 4))

                     If AttachmentFileType = ".ber" Then
                          'CurrentItem.Move (GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders(".PathErrors"))
                     End If

                Next CurrentAttachment

           End If

      Next CurrentItem

 End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect @Jean-PierreOosthuizen This is working. Can't believe this troubled me all day! Thank you very much.