# Move specific E-mails from a subfolder to another subfolder

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I would like to use a different code than in [Outlook VBA Macro to move mail from subfolder to subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37133599/outlook-vba-macro-to-move-mail-from-subfolder-to-subfolder)

The code I am using is from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869653.aspx.

I want to move emails from a subfolder instead of from the inbox. Let's say the subfolder I want to search for mails is called "Marketing".

The code I want to modify

```vb
Sub CreateRule() 
    Dim colRules As Outlook.Rules 
    Dim oRule As Outlook.Rule 
    Dim colRuleActions As Outlook.RuleActions 
    Dim oMoveRuleAction As Outlook.MoveOrCopyRuleAction 
    Dim oFromCondition As Outlook.ToOrFromRuleCondition 
    Dim oExceptSubject As Outlook.TextRuleCondition 
    Dim oInbox As Outlook.Folder 
    Dim oMoveTarget As Outlook.Folder 
 
    'Specify target folder for rule move action 
    Set oInbox = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) 
    'Assume that target folder already exists 
    Set oMoveTarget = oInbox.Folders("Advertisement") 
     
    'Get Rules from Session.DefaultStore object 
    Set colRules = Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules() 
     
    'Create the rule by adding a Receive Rule to Rules collection 
    Set oRule = colRules.Create("Advert rule", olRuleReceive) 
 
    'Specify the condition in a ToOrFromRuleCondition object 
    'Condition is if the message is from "xyz@abc.com" 
    Set oFromCondition = oRule.Conditions.From 
    With oFromCondition 
        .Enabled = True 
        .Recipients.Add ("xyz@abc.com") 
        .Recipients.ResolveAll 
    End With 
 
    'Specify the action in a MoveOrCopyRuleAction object 
    'Action is to move the message to the target folder 
    Set oMoveRuleAction = oRule.Actions.MoveToFolder 
    With oMoveRuleAction 
        .Enabled = True 
        .Folder = oMoveTarget 
    End With 
 
    'Specify the exception condition for the subject in a TextRuleCondition object 
    'Exception condition is if the subject contains "new" or "interest" 
    Set oExceptSubject = _ 
        oRule.Exceptions.Subject 
    With oExceptSubject 
        .Enabled = True 
        .Text = Array("new", "interest") 
    End With 
 
    'Update the server and display progress dialog 
    colRules.Save 
End Sub
```

I guess I need to modify these lines.

```vb
'Specify target folder for rule move action 
Set oInbox = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
```

Comment: From `Marketing` to `Where` ? all the email or specific emails?

Comment: From Marketing to Advertisement (Set oMoveTarget = oInbox.Folders("Advertisement"). And move all emails except for the ones with "new" or "interest" in the subject. This condition is currently covered already in the Exceptions code. Currently the code works by moving mails from "Inbox" to "Advertisement"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your sub-folder

```
'Specify target folder for rule move action
Set oInbox = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Marketing")
```

Comment: oh wow ... this worked like a charm...

It is exactly what i wanted! THanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The Folder class provides the [Folders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864011.aspx) property which returns the Folders collection that represents all the folders contained in the specified Folder.

If you need to get a folder named "Marketing" you can use the following code:

```
 Set oMoveTarget = oInbox.Folders("Marketing")
```

In case if the folder is located down to the tree you will have to call the Folders property recursively, for example, see [How to: Enumerate Folders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff184607.aspx).

Finally, you may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx) article helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll take a look at the link, but the answer I was looking for was adding the following so I could move the stuff from that subfolder. Thanks anyways!

Set oInbox = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Marketing")